# Haskell spec post doesn't work

Tags: haskell

I am currently writing a Haskell testing code, but the post part doesn't work.

```
    module Main where

      import           MyLib (app)
      import           Control.Monad       (mzero)
      import           Data.Aeson
      import           Test.Hspec
      import           Test.Hspec.Wai
      import           Data.Semigroup ((<>))

      --import           Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON
      --import           UseHaskellAPI
      data ResponseMsg = ResponseMsg { name    :: String
                                     , message :: String
                                     } deriving (Eq, Show)
      instance FromJSON ResponseMsg where
       parseJSON (Object o) =
         ResponseMsg <$> o .: "name"
                     <*> o .: "message"
       parseJSON _ = mzero

      instance ToJSON ResponseMsg where
        -- this generates a Value
        toJSON (ResponseMsg n m) =
            object ["name" .= n, "message" .= m]

        -- this encodes directly to a bytestring Builder
        toEncoding (ResponseMsg n m) =
            pairs ("name" .= n <> "message" .= m)


      main :: IO ()
      main = do
        --
        putStrLn $ show $ toJSON $ ResponseMsg "ecky" "hello"
        hspec spec

      spec :: Spec
      spec = with (return app) $ do
        --test case for sample storage message
        describe "POST /storeMessage true" $ do
          it "responds with storeMessage" $ do
            (post "/storeMessage" $ encode $ toJSON $ ResponseMsg "ecky" "hello") `shouldRespondWith` "true%" {matchHeaders = ["Content-Type" <:> "application/json"]}
```

The console output like this

test/Main.hs:48: 
      1) POST /storeMessage true responds with storeMessage
           status mismatch:
             expected: 200
             but got:  415
           missing header:
             Content-Type: application/json
           the actual headers were:
           body mismatch:
             expected: "true%"
             but got:  ""

This is the data type

```
    data Message = Message { name    :: String
                           , message :: String
                           } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToBSON, FromBSON)

    deriving instance FromBSON String  -- we need these as BSON does not provide
    deriving instance ToBSON   String
```

and this is server api

```
        storeMessage :: Message -> Handler Bool
        storeMessage msg@(Message key _) = liftIO $ do
          warnLog $ "Storing message under key " ++ key ++ "."
          withMongoDbConnection $ upsert (select ["name" =: key] "MESSAGE_RECORD") $ toBSON msg

          return True
```

does any one know the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the server was expecting `application/json` as the content type, but you didn't set it in your request.  It's hard to know for sure, since you didn't tell us anything at all about your server.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I uploaded my server api.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old message, but for those who would be looking for an answer today, here it is, I hope.

I don't know what the default `content-type` header is, but here it is clearly not `"application/json"`, so you have to specify it because that's what you are sending. So use `request` instead:

`request methodPost "/storeMessage" [(hApplicationContent, "application/json" :: ByteString)] $ encode $ toJSON $ ResponseMsg "ecky" "hello"`

See doc [Test.Hspec.Wai](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-wai-0.11.0/docs/Test-Hspec-Wai.html) and [headers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.12.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-Header.html#t:Header)